# Make particle group both perpendicular to normal and random

Tags: particles

I am making a succulent, and am having problems discovering how to make the leaves come straight out. Better yet, out and up. I can't get the leaves to touch the plant, let alone stick out of it.

Additionally, I can't seem to randomize my group of leaves. They come as they are, in a row. In the screenshot, you can see the array of leaves. I have turned them 90 degrees on the x-axis, both ways, and other axes also.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Change your Emitter Geometry Normal to 0
- Be aware of [edit mode] vs [object mode]
- Change your Rotation Panel / Initial Orientation to normal tangent.  This will depend on the [edit mode] orientation of your leaves.  In [edit mode] rotate your leaf by 90s degrees an an axis until you get the desired result.  You initial leaf orientiation should be lined up to the xyz axis much like your back is aligned with your spine.
- Set the affect of field weights panel/ gravity to 0

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made those changes and it still isn't doing what it is supposed to. The leaves will not touch the trunk no matter which direction I rotate the original.            I put it on "object" instead of "group", just to make it more simple to see. I will still need help randomizing the leaves and not have them all linked together as they populate. Now to figure out how to post a picture in a comment...